# bookdown figure caption width?

Tags: r, bookdown

I've just started writing my PhD thesis in Bookdown and so far things are going great. The one problem I do have though is that figure captions when outputted to PDF format seem to take up only about 60% of the page width, and are centered. This is great for short captions, but most of my figure captions are in the region of 50 words long for complicated panels. Is there some LaTeX magic to make them the width of the page?

Thanks
Tom

Here is what I'm using in my .md file:

```
| Reagent                  | Amount   |
| ------------------------ | -------- |
| Appropriate Buffer (10x) | 1x       |
| DNA                      | 50-500ng |
| Restriction Enzyme       | 1*U*     |
| Water                    | -        |

Table: (\#tab:restriction-generic) Schematic for restriction digestion with a single restriction enzyme.
```

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]?  For `bookdown` this is often possible via a Rmd file that uses `bookdown::pdf_document2` as output.

Comment: Added my table code to the OP. I am currently making simple tables (no R code) using Markdown alone, but I'd like all tables to be consistent: full width with full width captions

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the LaTeX package `caption`:

```
---
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_document2
header-includes:
- \usepackage[width=\textwidth]{caption}
---

This is an R Markdown document. Markdown is a simple formatting syntax for authoring HTML, PDF, and MS Word documents. For more details on using R Markdown see <http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com>.

| Reagent                  | Amount   |
| ------------------------ | -------- |
| Appropriate Buffer (10x) | 1x       |
| DNA                      | 50-500ng |
| Restriction Enzyme       | 1*U*     |
| Water                    | -        |

Table: (\#tab:restriction-generic) Schematic for restriction digestion with a single restriction enzyme. Some really long text that shows how the caption is formatted when it takes multiple lines.
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: That is great! My only other question would be - is there a simple way to also make tables the full page width? I've seen guides online about using things like longtable, but all of these imply using R to generate the tables and in the first instance I just want to make simple tables to hold reagent information.

Comment: @TomKent I don't know a way to influence the width of plain text tables. This is done automatically by [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#tables). as an alternative you could use plain LaTeX code for the table giving you full control over the output.